# Icons between text in a jlabel using graphics

Tags: java, swing, icons

How to paint multiple icons (ie., say icons between text) in `JLabel` using graphics? Please do assist me in this effort

Answer (score 1):

One option I would use is to have a sequence of JLabels. Ones with icon and ones with text only.

The other option would be to leverage the mini HTML support of the JLabel: Have

```
<html><img src='theimage.png'>The text<img src='theimage2.png'>
```

as the text of the JLabel. This approach works for text formatting but I'm not sure if the image tags work there too.

Or you did override the JLabel.paint() to do custom rendering btw?

Then I would use the following approach:

```
List<Object> textAndImage = new ArrayList<Object>() {{
    add("This ");
    add(new ImageIcon("image1.png"));
    add(" is ");
    add(new ImageIcon("image2.png"));
    add(" an ");
    add(" imaged text sample ");
}};
FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
int x = 0;
for (Object o : textAndImage) {
    if (o instanceof String) {
        g.drawString((String)o, x, fm.getHeight());
        x += fm.stringWidth((String)o);
    } else
    if (o instanceof ImageIcon) {
        ((ImageIcon)o).paintIcon(null, g, x, 0);
        x += ((ImageIcon)o).getIconWidth();
    }
}
```

Of course this is not a fully fledged solution but might give you some hints how to proceed.

Comment: <img> tags should work but HTML support in Swing is buggy as heck. One notable flaw is that whenever you use HTML the L&F-specified fonts do not work anymore.

Comment: The option of using <html> with images fetched dynamically doesnt work.
Did overriding of the paintComponent for JLabel but the sequence of text and image is not getting painted completely. should the jlabel size be set before paint?

Comment: Based on information of other posts, If you try to load BMPs or other non-supported images into an ImageIcon, that won't work. Use ImageIO.read() method to get the image. If the label does not have a size, it won't render anything. Try putting it into a BorderLayout-ed container into the CENTER region.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use a custom border that paints an icon (and text if you want), then you can nest indefinitely.

Here's one such border:

```
/**
 * Show a leading or trailing icon in border.
 */
public static class IconBorder implements Border
{
    /**
     * @param icon - icon to paint for this border
     * @param top outer insets for this border
     * @param left
     * @param bottom
     * @param right
     */
    public IconBorder(Icon icon, int top, int left, int bottom, int right)
    {
        setIcon(icon);
        top_ = top;
        left_ = left;
        bottom_ = bottom;
        right_ = right;
        rect_ = new Rectangle(0, 0, icon_.getIconWidth(), icon_.getIconHeight());
    }

    public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c)
    {
        if( icon_ == null )
            return new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
        return isTrailing_ ? new Insets(top_, left_, bottom_, icon_.getIconWidth() + right_) :
                             new Insets(top_, icon_.getIconWidth() + left_, bottom_, right_);
    }

    public boolean isBorderOpaque()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
        if( icon_ != null )
        {
            if( isTrailing_ )
                x = width - icon_.getIconWidth() + 4;
            else
                x += left_ - 1;
            icon_.paintIcon(c, g, x, y + top_);
            rect_.x = x;
            rect_.y = y;
        }
    }

    public void setIcon(Icon icon)
    {
        if( icon_ != icon )
            icon_ = icon;
    }

    public Icon getIcon()
    {
        return icon_;
    }

    public void setPosition(boolean isTrailing)
    {
        isTrailing_ = isTrailing;        
    }

    public Rectangle getIconRect()
    {
        return rect_;
    }

    private final int top_;
    private final int left_;
    private final int bottom_;
    private final int right_;
    private final Rectangle rect_;
    private Icon icon_;
    private boolean isTrailing_ = true;
}
```

I use this to add a search icon to a JTextField (a la browser search box). `getIconRect` can be used to check for mouse hover. For example I change cursor to `HAND_CURSOR` when mouse is over the search icon.